# android:- how to copy image from Assets to SD Card?

Tags: android

I have some images to be displayed in the Application (When user selects an image from it, like picking from gallery ).

The question is how to copy the images I am putting in the assets
   folder in the code to a folder on the SD card.

- Edit: I tried this example : http://www.technotalkative.com/android-copy-files-from-assets-to-sd-card/
- I have given the app permission to read and write

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: i tried image to push direct sdcard, but it not work.Then use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173468/copy-images-from-assest-to-sd-card-on-install-android-application

Answer (score 3):

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open(fileName);
```

Get the `AssetManager` and call `open` with the filename you want to copy as parameter.
Then you can simply copy in this way

```
File out = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LEN];
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
int read = 0;

 while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LEN)) >= 0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
  }

fos.flush();
fos.close()
is.close()
```

remember to add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: thank you for answer,this will be use for specified file but in my project there are images(not a single image).

Comment: It looks like Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory is a method, not public member, so it should be Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() (with braces)

Comment: yes of course. It was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out @Grimmy

Answer (score 2):

```
private void copyFileAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();            
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = assetManager.open("ceo.jpg");
          out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+ "abc.jpg");
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        }       

}
```

---

```
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

you have to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- Get the bitmap resource using one of the many ways.

Ex:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resource, id); // get your bitmap that you want to save on SD card.
```

- Get the path to store the resource.

`String compressedFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "FOLDERNAME" + File.separator + "FILENAME.jpg";`

- Save using compress method. (Shortcut way to save image as per [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html))

`bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToStore))); // use 100 to make sure image quality is not reduced(Read the docs)`

Note: You need Write(and may be read in future) access to write to SDCARD.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: so basically you are taking a compressed image, decompressing it, then recompressing it back on the sdcard. isn't it simpler to, like, copy it ?

Comment: Not quite. Take the image, call the compress method that in turn just returns the same image if compression value is set to 100. Its a simple way to save an image to any location. No compression nor decompression.

Comment: yes, there is. a jpeg is compressed, even if the compression is lossless. you are creating a bitmap from a jpeg (or whatever), hence decompressing it, then creating a new jpeg file, which is a compression.